# When I try to compile this C++ program, it gives me an error

Tags: c++

This is a program in which someone inputs a password and gets three tries to 
guess the password. When I compile it, I get multiple errors, one of which includes line 13, where it basically says that it cannot find a similar function included in the `Password_Program` class.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Password_Program
{
private:
     string password;
public:
     Password_Program();
     void login();
     string passAttempt;
};

Password_Program::Password_Program()
{
     cin >> password;
}
Password_Program::login()
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     {
          cin >> passAttempt;
          if (passAttempt == password)
          {
               cout << "Success!" << endl;
               break;
          }
          else if (i >= 3) { cout << "Try again later" << endl;
          break; }
          else { cout << "Sorry, try again" << endl; }
     }
}

int main() {
     Password_Program myPassword;
     myPassword.login;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: "it basically says that..." Please, when asking for help with an error, quote the error message verbatim.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. You need to define `void Password_Program::login()` (you omitted the return type).  It is helpful to identify the line with the error with a comment as it is not clear from my line counting that the trouble is on line 13 of the code pasted.  It also helps to include the exact error message.  You also need to distinguish between compiling a program and running the already compiled program — very different operations, and you get quite different error messages from the two processes.

Comment: In future, when you mention an error, it is best to post the error verbatim, and when you mention a line number, you should mark that line in your code.

Comment: It is not clear that you should be making `passAttempt` a public member; indeed, it isn't entirely clear why it is a member at all; it would be sufficient to make it a local variable to the `login()` program.

Answer (score 5):

Your definition of the `login()` method is missing a return type. It should be:

```
void Password_Program::login()
{
    ...
}
```

You've also forgotten brackets when calling it:

```
myPassword.login();
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the return type in  the definition of `Password_Program::login()`.

Change

```
Password_Program::login() {....}
```

to

```
void Password_Program::login() {....}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things are there

1. You did not added the **void** when defining the class function login outside the class.
2. Second that when you are calling login function you are missing **()**

Here is the right code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Password_Program
{
private:
     string password;
public:
     Password_Program();
     void login();
     string passAttempt;
};

Password_Program::Password_Program()
{
     cin >> password;
}
void Password_Program::login()
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     {
          cin >> passAttempt;
          if (passAttempt == password)
          {
               cout << "Success!" << endl;
               break;
          }
          else if (i >= 3) { cout << "Try again later" << endl;
          break; }
          else { cout << "Sorry, try again" << endl; }
     }
}

int main() {
     Password_Program myPassword;
     myPassword.login();
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: all 'yall. Thank You!!